# What is this number/identifier on a PS3 disc?

Tags: ps3

I was cleaning my old PS3 discs when I saw that there are 4 letters and a couple of numbers on the left side of the disc.

In the case of Uncharted 3: Drake's Deception, it is BPDL-246890:

[image]
[image]

What do these letters and numbers mean?

Comment: While I was writing this question, I saw that my disc of Uncharted 3 has a typo. It says "Estado Unidos" (United State) instead of "Estados Unidos" (United States) while describing the place where it was manufactured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [Manufacturing Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Digital_Audio_Disc_Corporation#Manufacturing_codes):

> Printed on the discs or packaging of Sony DADC-manufactured CDs are
>   codes indicating master copies (matrix numbers) of discs. These codes
>   begin with a 4-letter prefix followed by a series of digits.

In your case:

> BPDL - **PlayStation 3 Blu-ray Disc Dual-layer** titles

As I cannot find any other information, I'm guessing the six-digit suffix is referring to the specific title.

Comment: The digits might be the lot or manufacturing plant, because a Google search shows discs in Spanish with 246890 and other ones in English with 246800 (both made in the US).